# uploading picture

Tags: c#

Good day

Creating an Inventory system

created a db in sql, In visual c#, I created a form where products will be entered and allowing the user to upload an image of the item, How do I go about doing it?

I'm a c++ programmer, newly into visual c#

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [older post on uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158007/asp-net-uploaded-file) on uploading a file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd want to save the images in the database as well... You need to allow the user to select an image from his/her own harddisk (Open File Dialog), and then read the bytes and send them to the database (ADO.NET's `DbCommand`). ADO.NET supports streams for BLOBS.

Here is a example of the Open File Dialog:

```
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "images (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Stream myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
                    {
                        if (myStream != null)
                        {
                            // do something with the stream bytes here....
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```