# how to know the exact file size just before uploading in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, c#-4.0, file-upload

i am giving a field to user where he can upload any
 image file i want to check that the file should not
be more large then 350kb .... how to do this in c#

```
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                string mynewpath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Upload\\";
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    // here i want to check that if file size is more then 350kb then i will give error 

                    string[] extarray = new string[] { "image/jpeg", "image/jpg","image/png", "image/gif" };
                    var isallowedfile = extarray.Contains(file.ContentType);
                    if (!isallowedfile)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Only image files (.jpeg , .gif , .png ) are accepted, please browse a image file");
                        return View("SurveyOptions", model);
                    }
                    string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(mynewpath + filename);
                }
```

Comment: You cannot check the filesize on the server side before the actual upload...You can try to do some tricks client side, but I am not sure of best practises in this area...

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158007/asp-net-uploaded-file

Comment: will you recommend something ?

Comment: I don't do research for people.  This questin has been asked dozen times just in the related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In older browsers its not possible to get file size before uploading it,
   workaround for this is to embed hidden `flash(actionscript)` element to get the file size
2. In latest browesers you can use `HTML5 File API` to read file size

check jquery filedrop plugin (https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) which is based on `HTML5 file API`

--NJ

Comment: WOOHOO!  I hadn't read that this is possible now with HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

you should use somthing like this :

```
HttpPostedFile MyFile;
int FileLen;
System.IO.Stream MyStream;
MyFileCollection = Request.Files;
MyFile = MyFileCollection[0];
FileLen = MyFile.ContentLength;
```

FileLen is the size of your file !compare It with any size you would like . . .

And iif you want to get the filezize on clientside , as far as I know you can do that using html file uploader :

```
function validateFile()
{
var strFileName = document.form1.file1.value;
var strExtName = strFileName.substring(strFileName.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase();
alert(strFileName);
alert(strExtName);
var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var e = objFSO.getFile(strFileName);
var fileSize = e.size;
//file size limit for 10mb
if (fileSize > 10485760){
alert("maximum size of uploaded file should be less than 10 MB.");
return false; 
}
else
return true;
}


<input type ="file" id="file1" name="file1" contentEditable="false" onchange="validateFile();" />
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention the big security hole using FileSystemObject.